# How to delete all for a single value of a model in mongoose

Tags: database, mongoose, discord, discord.js

```
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose');
module.exports = model(
  'Profile',
  new Schema({
    userId: String,
    guildId: String, 
    daily: Number,
    weekly: Number,
    monthly: Number,
    total: Number,
    cooldown: Date
  })
);
```

This is my model for mongoose, how do i delete all values for "daily" of the model

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
Profile.updateMany({}, { $unset: { daily: 1 } })
```

Comment: it will make daily for all docs to "1" or null ?

Comment: it will delete the field from all data. So no more daily field. But I recommend you not try production data try on local first.